# How to send message by echo command to mac console? (Docker for Mac)

Tags: docker

I'm using Node server container on Docker for Mac.
And messages by node.js server are displayed on my mac console.

How can I display messages by bash script from inside container on my mac console?
I'm running shell script as well. and I want to show something messages by `echo something`

My docker-compose includes `healthcheck`, and echo is executed inside healthcheck.sh:

```
healthcheck: test: ["CMD", "bash", "-c", "/xxx/xxxx/healthcheck.sh"]
```

Thanks!

Comment: How did you start your container?

Comment: I'm using docker-compose.
So just `docker-compose up`

Comment: In that case everything written to `stdout` or `stderr` should go to the console, independent where it comes from. How do you run your shell script inside the container?

Comment: Year, I found it and tried it.
`echo 'aaa' > /dev/stdout`

Comment: My docker-compose includes healthcheck.
```
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "bash", "-c", "/xxx/xxxx/healthcheck.sh"]
```
And echo is executed inside healthcheck.sh

Comment: The fact that `echo` is inside `healtheck` is not trivial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your `echo` is executed inside docker `healthcheck`, its output is not sent to the container `stdout`. Docker store the healthcheck output as container meta-data:

> To help debug failing probes, any output text (UTF-8 encoded) that the command writes to stdout or stderr will be stored in the health status and can be queried with docker inspect. Such output should be kept short (only the first 4096 bytes are stored currently).

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck

So you can see that output using this:

```
docker inspect <container-id>
```

Looks like something like:

```
        "Health": {
            "Status": "unhealthy",
            "FailingStreak": 6,
            "Log": [
                {
                    "Start": "2017-06-17T19:39:33.001296235Z",
                    "End": "2017-06-17T19:39:33.059073965Z",
                    "ExitCode": 1,
                    "Output": "/bin/sh: 1: curl: not found\n"
                },
```

And to be more specific:

```
docker inspect <container-id> -f '{{index .State.Health.Log 0}}'
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it!!

Answer (score -1):

all messages written to stdout and stderr (which includes `echo`) are stored in the logs for the container.

so, you can tail the logs for the container and see the messages as they occur.

for a single container, you can run `docker logs -f <container name>`

for a docker-compose setup, run `docker-compose logs -f <service name>`

do this after starting your app